# Do I need PhD to do research in Linguistics?

Tags: linguistics

So I am finishing up a masters in Applied Linguistics in the UK. Do I need a PhD to do research in UK or U.S? I love research and want to do this for a living.

Thanks!

Comment: Check CVs of people who have the jobs you want.  I'm going to guess that most of them have PhDs, but be aware many people who have PhDs do not have research jobs.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to the kind of research you mean?

Answer (score 8):

No, you don't actually need a doctorate to "do research" in most fields. What a doctorate does is give you some training and experience in it and, importantly, connects you with people who can help and the systems in which it is normally done.

But there are "independent researchers" in most fields - especially those that don't require expensive labs and such in order to work. It is a bit harder without a doctorate, especially at the beginning.

And it is also much harder to *get hired* as a researcher without the degree(s) that are considered normal in that field.